# Get byte array byte Marshal

Tags: c#, arrays, marshalling

I have XgTunWrap.encapsulation()

```
UInt16 encapsulation(out IntPtr pkt, UInt32 src_ip, UInt32 dst_ip, UInt16 sport, UInt16 dport, UInt16 pktLen);
```

function (C++ dll in C#) which takes byte array pointer and encapsulates that byte array and returns length of byte array. I am trying to get encapsulated byte array using Marshalling but getting memory access violation error.

In below my source code which gives error. Is there any way to get encapsulated byte array?

```
int lenghtAr = Marshal.SizeOf(msg[0]) * msg.Length;
    IntPtr unmPont = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(lenghtAr);
    try
    {                            
      Marshal.Copy(msg, 0, unmPont, msg.Length);
      len = XgTunWrap.encapsulation(out unmPont, m_pList.m_DeviceHoA.IpAddress, item.m_VptAliasHoA.IpAddress, (ushort)taPort, (ushort)taPort, (short)msg.Length);
     res = new byte[len];
     Marshal.Copy(unmPont, res, 0, (int)len);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {throw; }
     finally
      {
      Marshal.FreeHGlobal(unmPont); 
     }
```

Comment: Why is the `XgTunWrap.encapsulation(out unmPont`  an _out_ parameter? It's strange, because you're just assigning/allocating mem on it.

Comment: `->>> catch (Exception ex) {throw; } <<<-- ` is useless.  Remove it, because the finally is always called.

Comment: Also `Marshal.Copy(msg, 0, unmPont, -> msg.Length <-);` **should be** `Marshal.Copy(msg, 0, unmPont, -> lenghtAr <-);`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Jeroen! I did as you commented. I removed `out` in front of `IntPtr`. And here is my working code:

```
UInt16 encapsulation(IntPtr pkt,
                     UInt32 src_ip,
                     UInt32 dst_ip,
                     UInt16 sport, 
                     UInt16 dport, 
                     UInt16 pktLen);
```

And working body:

```
int lengthAr = Marshal.SizeOf(msg[0]) * msg.Length;
IntPtr unmPont = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(lengthAr);

try
{
    Marshal.Copy(msg, 0, unmPont, lengthAr);
    len = XgTunWrap.encapsulation(unmPont,
                                  m_pList.m_DeviceHoA.IpAddress,
                                  item.m_VptAliasHoA.IpAddress,
                                  (ushort)taPort,
                                  (ushort)taPort,
                                  (ushort)msg.Length);
    res = new byte[len];
    Marshal.Copy(unmPont, res, 0, (int)len);                                                                         
}
finally
{
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(unmPont);
}
```